# How to view three different category of post in three different columns in wordpress?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, wordpress

I am really new in 'WordPress' and current facing a problem that is I am using FUNDA theme and try to show the three different category of post in three different column depending on category ID but can not find the post for a specific category.

I try this

```
<?php 
    $data = cats_to_select(); 
    $cat_id = $data[1][value];
    global $cat_id;?>
    <?php print_r($cat_id);?>

<?php if($cat_id==3):?>
    <?php if (have_posts()) : ?>    
    <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
    <div <?php post_class() ?> id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
                                        <?php if ( function_exists("has_post_thumbnail") && has_post_thumbnail() ) { the_post_thumbnail(array(260,200), array("class" => "alignleft post_thumbnail")); } ?>
                                        <h2 class="title"><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
                                        <div class="postdate"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/date.png" /> <?php the_time('F jS, Y') ?> <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/user.png" /> <?php the_author() ?> <?php if (current_user_can('edit_post', $post->ID)) { ?> <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/edit.png" /> <?php edit_post_link('Edit', '', ''); } ?></div>

                                <div class="entry">
                                    <?php the_content('<strong>Read more &raquo;</strong>'); ?>
                                </div>
                                    </div><!--/post-<?php the_ID(); ?>-->

<?php endwhile; ?>
<div class="navigation">
<?php if(function_exists('wp_pagenavi')) { wp_pagenavi(); } else { ?>
<div class="alignleft"><?php next_posts_link('&laquo; Older Entries') ?></div>
<div class="alignright"><?php previous_posts_link('Newer Entries &raquo;') ?></div>
<?php } ?>
</div>
<?php else : ?>
<h2 class="center">Not Found</h2>
<p class="center">Sorry, but you are looking for something that isn't here.</p>
                                <?php get_search_form(); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Can any one help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you please format your code, so we can read it better? The way it looks now is not very inviting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php query_posts('cat=3'); ?> // here, 3 will be replaced with desired
                             // category id, or you may add array 
<?php if (have_posts()) : ?>    
    <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
    <div <?php post_class() ?> id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
                                        <?php if ( function_exists("has_post_thumbnail") && has_post_thumbnail() ) { the_post_thumbnail(array(260,200), array("class" => "alignleft post_thumbnail")); } ?>
                                        <h2 class="title"><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
                                        <div class="postdate"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/date.png" /> <?php the_time('F jS, Y') ?> <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/user.png" /> <?php the_author() ?> <?php if (current_user_can('edit_post', $post->ID)) { ?> <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/edit.png" /> <?php edit_post_link('Edit', '', ''); } ?></div>

                                <div class="entry">
                                    <?php the_content('<strong>Read more &raquo;</strong>'); ?>
                                </div>
                                    </div><!--/post-<?php the_ID(); ?>-->

<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

That code only shows one category. You would need to add an array of the category ids and possible use a for loop to multiply the code, instead of the if statement. Maybe something like that.

Then make a bit of css that would divide the content into different boxes? I'm not sure what you mean by three columns. Also not sure what the FUNDA theme is.

It would be easier if you could give us a better idea of what you're using. Link?